# NullPointerException when looking at String

Tags: java, string, url, nullpointerexception

I'm making a web crawler that searches for the first (user inputted) number of links on a page that contains a phrase.  I'm crawling just fine, but I'm getting NullPointerExceptions when I try to see if the link contains the phrase.  This is the code I'm using to do it:

```
private boolean linkContainsSearchFor(URL url){
    boolean ans = false;

    In urlIn = new In(url);
    String urlText = "";

    //if urlIn is null, get out now to avoid nullpointerexceptions
    if (urlIn == null)
        return ans;

    urlText = urlIn.readAll();
    System.out.println("urlText="+urlText);

    if(urlText.contains(searchFor)){
        ans = true;
        System.out.println("found a match!");
    }

    return ans;
}
```

The readAll() method just reads the entire web page in as text and returns it as one giant String.  There shouldn't be anything wrong there, but that's the line that's giving me the error.  Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the error screen.[image: Here's the error screen]

EDIT #2:  This is the readAll() method:

```
/**
 * Read and return the remainder of the input as a string.
 */
public String readAll() {
    if (!scanner.hasNextLine())
        return "";

    String result = scanner.useDelimiter(EVERYTHING_PATTERN).next();
    // not that important to reset delimeter, since now scanner is empty
    scanner.useDelimiter(WHITESPACE_PATTERN); // but let's do it anyway
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: display error  screen here would be useful

Comment: The line giving the error is `urlText = urlIn.readAll();`

Comment: please put the definition of method readAll();

Comment: `urlIn` can't possibly be null in your code, even without the extra null check, because `new` never returns null. Add the exception to your post.

Comment: It can not open  the link which you are trying to access see the first line in exception

Comment: I put the readAll() method up, but since that's code I got from my text book, I'm fairly sure it isn't the problem.  @immibis I know that `urlIn` can't be null, that's why I'm so confused.

Comment: where is the searchFor defined in your code. upload a  sample of the url and the search string that you are searching for

Comment: Notice that there is another message interleaved with the stack trace, and the stack trace is helpfully highlighted in red.

Comment: `searchFor` is defined in the constructor. The URL I start with is `http://slashdot.org` and crawl from there. A sample search string would be `test` or `hello` or something similar.

Comment: @immibis Do you mean the `Could not open ...` line?  I see that, but there shouldn't be a way to get to this method at all if the page didn't open.  Is that what you think is happening?

Comment: I mean the "at In.readAll(In.java:244)" line.

Comment: Have you considered trying to use debugger? Just put breakpoint before the line where NPE is thrown.

Comment: What is on line 244 of file In.java? Also, are you initializing "scanner" while constructing "In"?

Comment: Line 244 of In.java is `if (!scanner.hasNextLine())`

Answer (score 0):

if `!scanner.hasNextLine()` throws the exception, it means that the scanner is null.